# min_doc_count in cardinality ? elasicsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i'm trying to perform what it appears to be a simple query but i cant get it to work.

I want to group the recors by some key, and count the ones that have more than "n" records. 
cardinality is not working because it does not support the min_count, so it counts all the keys, not only the ones that has more or equal than "n" records.

example:

key1 , 5 records 
key2 , 1 record 
key3 , 4 records 
key4 , 1 record

n=3,
the result should be "2"

in sql could be something like this

```
select count(*) 
from (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM  my_table
    where my_field = "foo"
    GROUP BY key
    Having count(*)>1
) as a;
```

thanks!

Comment: Why not simply using a `terms` aggregation with `min_doc_count: 3` and then count the number of buckets?

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply, because it returns like a million documents and it takes very long, i want the top documents and the count